# AngularJS $setValidity within linking function sets the validity of the wrong element/form. Not accessible within unit test

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm setting the validity of a form in the linking function of my directive and it works in practice. However, it seems to be putting the validator on the wrong element and I'm not able to access it in the Jasmine unit test. Here is a stripped down version of what I've done:

The directive is part of a nested form, though I don't think this makes a difference:

```
// directive view
<tfoot ng-form="formStep">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div test-directive ng-model="testDirective.model" ng-change="checkValidity()"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

In the linking function, I'm getting the modelController for the form (or is it the controller for the directive? I'm unclear on this.)

```
// directive linking function
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
        .directive('testDirective', testDirective);

    testDirective.$inject = [];

    function testDirective() {
        return {
            restrict : 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope : {
            },
            replace : true,
            template: require('./test.directive.partial.html'),
            link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModelController){
                scope.checkValidity = checkValidity;

                function checkValidity(){
                        ngModelController.$setValidity('testError', false);
                }
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

In the directive partial that follows, the validator ends up on the

```
<div class="testDirective">
```

rather than

```
<div ng-form="testDirectiveForm">
```

So the end result of the code when the input changes is

```
<div class="testDirective ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ng-invalid-test-error ng-dirty ng-valid-parse">
```

(at least when logged from the unit test.)

```
// test.directive.partial.html
<div class="testDirective">
    <div ng-form="testDirectiveForm">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" ng-model="testModel.test" ng-value="true" required ng-change="checkValidity()" />                           
                <strong>option 1</strong>
            </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the unit test, if I console.log element.isolateScope().testDirectiveForm.$error it contains an error for required if I don't set a value for the input. However, it does not contain an error for testError. That seems to get put on the element above it.

```
// Unit test
describe('testDirective', function () {
    var $scope;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope){
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));
    describe('link function', function(){
        var createElement, element, isolateScope;
        beforeEach(inject(function($compile){   
            $scope.ngModel;
            element = angular.element('<div test-directive></div>');
            element.attr('ng-model', 'ngModel');
            createElement = function(){
                element = $compile(element)($scope);
            };
        }));
        describe('after link', function () {
            beforeEach(inject(function () {
                createElement();
            }));
            describe('after initialization', function () {
                beforeEach(function () {
                    $scope.$apply();
                    isolateScope = element.isolateScope();
                });
                it('.checkValidity should set the the error to testError', inject(function($rootScope){
                    isolateScope.checkValidity();
                    $rootScope.$digest();

                    console.log(isolateScope.testDirectiveForm.$error.testError);
                    expect(isolateScope.testDirectiveForm.$error.testError).toBeDefined();
                }));
            });
        });     
    });
});
```

What's going on here? I think the controller I'm getting in the linking function belongs to the directive, but I'm not able to see the validator or see any way to check it if I log "element.scope()" in the test. Is there a better way to to any of this?

Comment: The statement "I'm getting the ng-model controller for the form" doesn't make sense. There is a [form controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) for each form directive and an [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) for each input.

Comment: Why do you want to create a form for each input? Also you don't need to use ng-change to check the validy. You can use the [validator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators) object of the model controller

Comment: @georgeawg How would I get the controller for the testDirectiveForm in this case. I want to access it from within the directive.

Comment: @MrWook Could you provide an example of how to use validators in this context? Will it be unit testable? A requirement of the project is 100% code coverage.

Comment: I actually solved this by getting the controller from element.data()

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms - Custom Validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by getting the model controller from element.data() in the test like so:

```
// Unit test
describe('testDirective', function () {
    var $scope, modelController;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope){
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    }));
    describe('link function', function(){
        var createElement, element, isolateScope;
        beforeEach(inject(function($compile){
            $scope.ngModel;
            element = angular.element('<div test-directive></div>');
            element.attr('ng-model', 'ngModel');
            createElement = function(){
                element = $compile(element)($scope);
            };
        }));
        describe('after link', function () {
            beforeEach(inject(function () {
                createElement();
            }));
            describe('after initialization', function () {
                beforeEach(function () {
                    $scope.$apply();
                    isolateScope = element.isolateScope();
                    modelController = element.data().$ngModelController;
                });
                it('.checkValidity should set the the error to testError', inject(function(){
                    isolateScope.checkValidity();
                    expect(modelController.$error.testError).toBeDefined();
                }));
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I tried using $validators and it worked for one of the components I'm working on (with the same unit test being valid). However, another component I was working on failed to run the validator each time the view was updated. Maybe something to do with nested form controllers? The code went like this for that:

```
ngModelController.$validators.testError = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
    if (!(viewValue && viewValue.length)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
};
```

I was also able to access the form on the isolate scope by putting the validator on the testDirectiveForm using scope in the linking function like so:

```
function checkValidity(){
    scope.testDirectiveForm.$setValidity('testError', false);
}
```

That's easily unit testable with what I had done originally:

```
it('.checkValidity should set the the error to testError', inject(function($rootScope){
        isolateScope.checkValidity();
        $rootScope.$digest();

        console.log(isolateScope.testDirectiveForm.$error.testError);
        expect(isolateScope.testDirectiveForm.$error.testError).toBeDefined();
}));
```

However, it didn't come out consistently with how the rest of the work in the project is being done.

Hope some of this helps someone. Thanks everyone for your answers.